# getting exception while execution of selenium web driver program

Tags: eclipse, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am executing simple java program and trying to execute my first selenium script.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the html unit driver
        // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
        // not the implementation.
        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
        element.submit();

        // Check the title of the page
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        driver.quit();
    }
```

these are the dependencies that i have added:[image: dependencies that I have added]

But after running this code I am getting this exception in eclipse.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.xni.XNIException
```

Comment: Why do you have xerces.jar , I don't think it is required to run selenium script. Remove that and try once again.

Answer (score 0):

`ClassNotFoundException` occurs mostly when the class file is not found in the specified class path. So try removing the xerces.jar and add it again.

Comment: I was doing it before without xerces.jar but it was throwing the exception that I have mentioned. so I added this jar. now again I removed the jar but getting same exception. :(